# Boost.Asio UDP socket, An invalid argument was supplied error

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, udp, tello-drone

I am trying to create a thread to listen for UDP responses in c++ using the Boost ASIO library, this is my definition for the receive thread in my class file:

```
tello::tello(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::ip::udp::socket& socket, const boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint& remote_endpoint)
    : ip(remote_endpoint.address().to_string()),
    port(remote_endpoint.port()),
    io_service(io_service),
    socket(socket),
    remote_endpoint(remote_endpoint)
{

}

void tello::ReceiveThread() {
    while (isListening_) {
        try {
            char receivedData[1024];
            boost::system::error_code error;

            size_t len = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(receivedData), remote_endpoint, 0, error);

            if (error && error != boost::asio::error::message_size) {
                throw boost::system::system_error(error);
            }

            receivedData[len] = '\0';

            spdlog::info("Received UDP data: {}", receivedData);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Error receiving UDP data: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void tello::StartListening() {
    std::thread udpThread(&tello::ReceiveThread, this);
    udpThread.detach(); // Detach the thread so it runs independently
}

void tello::StopListening() {
    isListening_ = false;
}
```

In my main.cpp I have this snippet to start the thread:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.0.1"), 12345); // Replace with the actual IP address and port
socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

tello drone(io_service, socket, remote_endpoint);
drone.StartListening();
```

The code compiles with no errors, but trying to run the app results in the console error:

`Error receiving UDP data: An invalid argument was supplied [system:10022 at C:\Users\(username)\boost_1_82_0\boost\asio\detail\win_iocp_socket_service.hpp:418:5 in function 'receive_from']`

I'm very new to Boost ASIO and would appreciate some help as to what the proper way to create a UDP receive thread. I'm using Windows 64bit with C++14. The full code is [here](https://github.com/TheBozzz34/Tello-GUI/) on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have data races.

You start a thread which references both `io_service` and `socket` which are local variables in `main`. However, `main` exits immediately, destructing those local variables.

The thread, which was detached, still runs causing [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of the stale references.

---

Fix it by

```
(a) avoiding the run-away thread
(b) also synchronizing on its termination
```

Also fixing some other issues and making up some code that might also be less safe (e.g. the potentially racy `isListening_`). There are more issues hiding
e.g.

- remote_endpoint is probably used for local endpoint as well
- no bind was happening on the listening socket
- `startListening` may be more aptly named `startReceive`
- blocking receive_from may never return so the thread would never stop unless data was received or an error occurred
- the `catch` block seems inefficient since it would only handle the error thrown locally

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddfa9bc844ff403f)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::udp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace spdlog {
    void info(auto fmt, auto const&... args) { fmt::print(fmt::runtime(fmt), args...); }
} // namespace spdlog

struct tello {
    tello(asio::io_context& io_context, udp::socket& socket, udp::endpoint const& remote_endpoint);

    void StartListening();

    void StopListening();
    void ReceiveThread();

  private:
    std::string       ip;
    uint16_t          port;
    asio::io_context& io_context;
    udp::socket&      socket;
    udp::endpoint     remote_endpoint;
    std::atomic_bool  isListening_{true};
    std::thread       udpThread;
};

tello::tello(asio::io_context& io_context, udp::socket& socket, udp::endpoint const& remote_endpoint)
    : ip(remote_endpoint.address().to_string())
    , port(remote_endpoint.port())
    , io_context(io_context)
    , socket(socket)
    , remote_endpoint(remote_endpoint) //
{
    socket.bind(remote_endpoint);
}

void tello::ReceiveThread() {
    for (char receivedData[1024]; isListening_;) {
        try {
            error_code error;
            size_t len = socket.receive_from(asio::buffer(receivedData), remote_endpoint, 0, error);

            if (error && error != asio::error::message_size) {
                throw boost::system::system_error(error);
            }

            receivedData[len] = '\0';

            spdlog::info("Received UDP data: {}", std::string_view(receivedData, len));
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "Error receiving UDP data: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void tello::StartListening() { udpThread = std::thread(&tello::ReceiveThread, this); }

void tello::StopListening() {
    isListening_ = false;
    udpThread.join();
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context io_context;
    udp::socket      socket(io_context);
    udp::endpoint    remote_endpoint({}, 12345);
    socket.open(udp::v4());
    tello drone(io_context, socket, remote_endpoint);
    drone.StartListening();


    std::this_thread::sleep_for(30s);
    drone.StopListening();
}
```

Local demo:

[image]

### BONUS

You want to use async IO so you can have much better behaviour. I think ironically it's a little bit simpler (about 30 LoC less):

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd95f25a0cec9483)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::udp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace spdlog {
    void info(auto fmt, auto const&... args) { fmt::print(fmt::runtime(fmt), args...); }
} // namespace spdlog

struct tello {
    tello(asio::any_io_executor ex, udp::endpoint ep);

    void Start() { readLoop(); }
    void Stop();
  private:
    void readLoop() {
        socket_.async_receive_from(
            asio::buffer(buffer_), remote_ep_, [this](error_code ec, size_t len) {
                if (ec && ec != asio::error::message_size) {
                    std::cerr << "Error receiving UDP data: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                } else {
                    spdlog::info("Received UDP data: {}", std::string_view(buffer_.data(), len));
                    readLoop();
                }
            });
    }

    udp::socket            socket_;
    udp::endpoint          remote_ep_;
    std::array<char, 1024> buffer_;
};

tello::tello(asio::any_io_executor ex, udp::endpoint ep) : socket_(ex, ep.protocol()) { socket_.bind(ep); }

void tello::Stop() { socket_.cancel(); }

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    tello drone(ioc.get_executor(), {{}, 12345});
    drone.Start();

    ioc.run_for(30s);
    // not really needed:
    drone.Stop();
    ioc.run();
}
```

And more local demo:

[image]

Comment: My apologies, I didn't add the rest of the code which was an issue on my part. The code is part of a GUI so the main thread stays open. You can view the rest of the code here. https://github.com/TheBozzz34/Tello-GUI/.

Comment: Luckily that doesn't change the answer (though you'd typically integrate an async solution differently, but without fundamentally changing)

Comment: Hm, okay updating the code prevents the invalid argument error, but setting the remote endpooint with boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.10.1") for the address instead of {} crashes the program on launch. @sehe

Comment: I can only guess there is an exception (which makes sense if 192.168.10.1 is not the address of a LOCAL network adaptor. Like I said, your code confuses local and remote endpoints at least in the naming). Other than that, there can be [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) elsewhere causing the symptom.

Comment: Ah yes, using a valid local adapter seems to work.